# Flutter showSearch async operation when building suggestions

Tags: android, asynchronous, flutter, dart

I am using the flutter showSearch function to search for addresses. Everything works fine so far.    Now I want to implement suggestions that will be rebuild each time the user changes the search input. To do this I am using the flutter geocode library.

The problem is that I don't know how I can execute an async operation when building suggestions using the buildSuggestions function.

Obviously I cannot simple make the buildSuggestions function async, but if I could my code would look like this:

```
@override
Future<Widget> buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) async {

  var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);

  final Iterable<Address> suggestions = query.isEmpty
      ? _history
      : addresses;

  return _SuggestionList(
    query: query,
    suggestions: suggestions.map<String>((String i) => '$i').toList(),
    onSelected: (String suggestion) {
      query = suggestion;
      this.close(context, query);
    },
  );
}
```

There must be ways of achieving what I want to do. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

With the help of the post from frank06 I wrote the following code:

```
   @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Address>> snapshot) {
          // check if snapshot.hasData

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            List<Address> addresses;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              addresses = snapshot.data;
            } else {
              addresses = List<Address>();
            }

            List<String> addressNames = addresses.map((address) {
              return address.addressLine;
            }).toList();

            final Iterable<String> suggestions =
                query.isEmpty ? _history : addressNames;

            return _SuggestionList(
              query: query,
              suggestions: suggestions.map<String>((String i) => '$i').toList(),
              onSelected: (String suggestion) {
                query = suggestion;
                this.close(context, query);
              },
            );
          } else {
            return _SuggestionList(
                query: query,
                suggestions: List<String>(),
                onSelected: (String suggestion) {
                  query = suggestion;
                  this.close(context, query);
                });
          }
        });
  }
```

I feel like I have gotten a lot closer to the solution, but currently I have the problem that snapshot.hasData always returns false.

Any further suggestions?

**FINAL UPDATE:**

Finally it did work. My future was not returning data because I hadn't made sure that my query was actually of datatype String. The code below is the final functioning version. (Thanks again to frank06!).

```
@override
 Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
   String queryString = query;

   return FutureBuilder(
       future: queryString.length > 0 ? Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(queryString) : Future.value(List<Address>()),
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Address>> snapshot) {

         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
           List<Address> addresses;
           if (snapshot.hasData) {
             addresses = snapshot.data;
           } else {
             addresses = List<Address>();
           }

           List<String> addressNames = addresses.map((address) {
             return address.addressLine;
           }).toList();

           final Iterable<String> suggestions =
               query.isEmpty ? _history : addressNames;

           return _SuggestionList(
             query: query,
             suggestions: suggestions.map<String>((String i) => '$i').toList(),
             onSelected: (String suggestion) {
               query = suggestion;
               this.close(context, query);
             },
           );
         } else {
           return _SuggestionList(
               query: query,
               suggestions: List<String>(),
               onSelected: (String suggestion) {
                 query = suggestion;
                 this.close(context, query);
               });
         }
       });
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
Future<Widget> buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      // check if snapshot.hasData
      var addresses = snapshot.data;

      final Iterable<Address> suggestions = query.isEmpty
          ? _history
          : addresses;

      return _SuggestionList(
        query: query,
        suggestions: suggestions.map<String>((String i) => '$i').toList(),
        onSelected: (String suggestion) {
          query = suggestion;
          this.close(context, query);
        },
      );
   )
}
```

`FutureBuilder` is built on top of `StatefulWidget`. Attempting to solve this problem with a `StatefulWidget` is not *wrong* but simply lower-level and more tedious.

This article explains it in detail: https://flutterigniter.com/build-widget-with-async-method-call/

Comment: Hey frank, thank you for your post! 
I see what you are suggesting. I think it might work, atm I am just having the problem that snapshot.hasData always returns false.

Comment: You're welcome Jakub, did you check `hasError`? is your future actually working?

Comment: @Jakub try `future: Future.value([Address(), Address()])` (e.g. two dummy addresses) and if that does work with `snapshot.data` then the problem is with your future

Comment: Thank you again, you have been very helpful! 
The problem was, that my future did not actually return any data, because the "query" was not of type String. After I had casted the query to String everything worked perfectly (: